# How to run a docker container with pm2?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, pm2

I have a system that has many components and one of them is a docker container.
I'd like to manage all these components with Pm2.

I'm able to run the `Node.js` scripts with Pm2, but I have a problem starting the docker container on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

I have a script "start.sh" that already starts the docker container in the right way.

The script is:

```
docker run -d -it -p 21083:21083 -p 9001:9001 -v /home/myhome/mqtt_broker/conf/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf -v /home/myhome/mqtt_broker/authentication/auth.txt:/mosquitto/auth.txt -v /home/myhome/mqtt_broker/acl/aclfile.txt:/mosquitto/aclfile.txt eclipse-mosquitto
```

I'm trying to start this script with PM2 in this way:

*`pm2 start /home/myhome/mqtt_broker/startBroker.sh  --name=BrokerMqtt`*

After launching this command I can see:

- 'docker ps' says that the container is up,
- BrokerMqtt in the processes list of pm2 with the status 'errored',
- in the log of pm2 I can see many of these errors:

  docker:

  > Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint jolly_meninsky (fefe45df2d338d89a4f8232873779e41bcaa1b846a463bc035d59c5ae09b26e0): Bind for 0.0.0.0:21083 failed: port is already allocated.

Why the script `start.sh`, that works if launched alone, fails with Pm2?

Comment: can you post the dockerfile? from the offical docker image it seems the process already started as a entery point, so when you tried to restart with pm2 the port is already occupied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try using `pm2` with `npm start`. In your `package.json` file, add a start script

```
  "start": "/home/myhome/mqtt_broker/startBroker.sh && sleep 5 && node Node"
```

Then you can start your application with

```sh
pm2 start npm --name BrokerMqtt -- start
```

You can adjust the time of `sleep`, I added that to make sure the container is ready to serve your node program.

Improvements you can make:

1. give a name to the container
2. make sure that container is not running before you run your bash script, here's one way to check:

```sh
docker inspect container_name|grep Running
```